# How to getElementsByClassName from IE to XL

Tags: excel, internet-explorer, getelementsbyclassname

I get errors using getelementsbyclassname in this code, and would like some hints to what I am doing wrong. I am successfully using getelementbyID, but classname always gives errors for me.

```
Set objExplorer = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
WebSite = "http://charting.nasdaq.com/ext/charts.dll?2-1-14-0-0-512-03NA000000ABT-&SF:1|8|27-SH:8=200|

27=10-BG=FFFFFF-BT=0-WD=635-HT=395--XTBL-"
WScript.Sleep 1000
With objExplorer
    .Navigate2 WebSite
    .Left=5
    .Top=5
    .Height=1000
    .Width=700
    .AddressBar = 0
    .Visible = 1
    .ToolBar = 0
    .StatusBar = 0
   WScript.Sleep 3000
End With

Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xl.Visible = True
Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\user\Documents\CI\testauto.xlsx")
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
WScript.Sleep 2000

ws.Range("G9").Value = objExplorer.document.getElementsByClassName("DrillDownData").innerText

WScript.Sleep 1000

objExplorer.Quit
```

Comment: You need to specify which Class Name you want. getElementsByClassName returns a collection of all elements with that Class Name. Something like: objExplorer.document.getElementsByClassName("DrillDownData")(0).InnerText should do the trick. The (0) means, select the first Class Name in the collection.

Comment: Hi Ryan, this might indeed be useful as I am only interested in the first four values. However, I still get an object not supported error for the getelement line..

Comment: Notice, that IE<9 don't support `gEBCN`.

Comment: I managed to make it work for another website (after adding (0) as suggested), but this site still gives errors. Any other suggestions I can check?